# How to write python to show Toruses from an imported txt file containing center coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a question about Python. By the way, I'm beginner of Python and English. I wrote a script showing Toruses from an imported txt file containing center coordinates, but I got an error at

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(location=(int(temp[0]), int(temp[1]), int(temp[2])), rotation=(math.pi/2, math.pi/2, math.pi/2))
```

I would appreciate if you tell me how to solve it.
Here is my script

```
import bpy
import math

f=open(r"C:\Users\biostr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\traj_pro.txt", "r")
lines=[]

for line in f:
    lines.append(line.strip())

for p in lines:
     temp=p.split(',')
     bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(location=(int(temp[0]), int(temp[1]), int(temp[2])), rotation=(math.pi/2, math.pi/2, math.pi/2))
     bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
     obj=bpy.context.scene.objects.active
     mat=bpy.data.materials.new('Torus')
     mat.diffuse_color=(1.0, 0, 0)
     mat.alpha=0.8
     obj.data.materials.append(mat)

f.close()
```

Here is some lines from my txt file. Actually, my file is Atom's coordinates, can I make Toruses from this??

CRYST1   65.961   65.961   65.961  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1

ATOM      1  N   GLN X   1      32.110  46.350  52.070  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2  H1  GLN X   1      32.470  45.850  52.870  1.00  0.00
ATOM      3  H2  GLN X   1      32.931  46.641  51.559  1.00  0.00
ATOM      4  H3  GLN X   1      31.568  47.112  52.451  1.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CA  GLN X   1      31.200  45.480  51.230  1.00  0.00
ATOM      6  HA  GLN X   1      30.402  45.041  51.829  1.00  0.00
ATOM      7  CB  GLN X   1      30.390  46.250  50.180  1.00  0.00
ATOM      8  HB1 GLN X   1      30.811  46.160  49.179  1.00  0.00

Comment: Could you add a few example lines from your text file to your post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I put some lines from the txt file. Although it is Atom's coordinates, I want to show Toruses on Blender by using it. Is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is based on on some old code but is still functional for blender 2.79. This will add a tool panel in the view3d viewport that will allow for file selection before generating a generic torus since the atom data only provides x,y,z coordinates as relevant info.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel


class MeshGenTool():
    @classmethod
    def main(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        objs = importFile(scene['File'])
        for obj in objs:
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(
                location=obj[0])
            MyMesh = context.object
            MyMesh.name = "MyMesh"


class MeshGenButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Execute generation"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Generate"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        filevalid = (scene.File is not "")
        return filevalid is True

    def execute(self, context):
        MeshGenTool.main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def importFile(File):
    obj_loc = ()
    obj_dia = 1
    obj_data = ()
    objs = []
    f = open(File, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ATOM'):
            words = line.split()
            obj_loc = (float(words[6]), float(words[7]), float(words[8]))
            obj_data = (obj_loc, obj_dia)
            objs.append(obj_data)
    return objs


class VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Import Atom Coords"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_label = "Import Coords"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        row = layout.row()
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(scene, "File")
        col.operator(
            "object.simple_operator", text="Add items",
            icon='MESH_TORUS')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MeshGenButton)
    bpy.types.Scene.File = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="File",
        description="Path of File to read from",
        default="",
        subtype='FILE_PATH')


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MeshGenButton)
    del bpy.types.Scene.File

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness. It worked very well. I really appreciate it. I have to study computer programs more and more to be able to write it like you.