# Create Group of Cylinders from a TXT file

Tags: import

I need to visualize a large group (say 200, 300) of cylinders from coordinates stored in a text file. One cylinder per line, defined by X1,Y1,Z1 and X2,Y2,Z2 (start and end), and by a diameter.

Is it possible just to import this TXT file and visualize all cylinders?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points/76629#76629 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71458/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-use-the-values-as-x-and-y-points-in-blender/71466#71466 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27536/csv-import-pointcloud-into-blender/27592#27592 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126690/how-to-write-python-to-show-toruses-from-an-imported-txt-file-containing-center

Comment: If you should still have questions how to implement this, i wrote a script which does this, which i will supply if you still need it. However the previous commenter has already given sufficient resources so it should be relatively easy to implement this yourself.

Comment: This might also be useful for getting the rotations right: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_release/mathutils.html

Comment: answers like the first one made me quit this program. thanks anyway.

Comment: I like blender and i think you might like blender also if you give it some patience and i understand your initial frustration with trying too much in one time at the first contact with blender. Therefore in order to help you get familiar with blender, i posted my pyhon code for this in the "duplicate" question. You can copy it into the editor window of blender and run it. Put your .txt at the location of blender.exe. I believe providing code makes sense here, because no solution was given there how to achieve the desired rotations. I hope you have not given up and will still see this comment.